# Check JSON response for Undefined type

Tags: javascript, json

I asked a similar question a little while ago but realised I was way off topic. I am making a call to my backend which reads a JSON file and returns the response

```
public function getData()
{
    return json_decode(file_get_contents($file_path, true));
}
```

The file that is being returned from the backend takes the following form

```
[
  [
    //Some data
  ],
  [
    //Some data
  ],
  [
    {
      "Category": "basketball",
      "Count": 12
    },
    {
      "Category": "football",
      "Count": 34
    },
    {
      "Category": "baseball",
      "Count": 244
    },
    {
      "Category": "softball",
      "Count": 11
    }
  ]
]
```

So it is a mixture of arrays and an array of objects.  The above array of objects is what I am interested in.  On the frontend, I am trying to handle this data.  At the moment I do something like

```
const catOne = response.data[2][0]['Count'];
const catTwo = response.data[2][1]['Count'];
const catThree = response.data[2][2]['Count'];
const catFour = response.data[2][3]['Count'];
```

What I have noticed however is that sometimes the file that is being passed back does not have 4 categories. As such, I am getting the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Count' of undefined
```

I was wondering what the best way to handle this would be?  I do not really want a load of if/else statements as this will look messy.  Can I do some type of ternary check to see if the value is undefined?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'd take the following path to this:
Create a category array and then iterate over it for the count, since you didn't specify your use case I'm not sure if this is applicable for you.

But what you'd do with this is something along these lines:

```
const categories = [];
for ( let i = 0; i < response.data[2].length; i++) {
    let response_data = response.data[2][i];
    if (response_data !== undefined) {
         categories.push(response_data); // You could also be pushing the count in here
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvoted. This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the array exists before accessing the "Count" property:

```
const catOne = (2 in response.data && 0 in response.data[2]) ? response.data[2][0]['Count'] : None;
```

But you should probably also be iterating through response.data[2] instead of hard coding the categories like that as well...

Answer (score 0):

The length of the arrays should not be hardcoded. Simply use a for loop and check the array length each time.